# Deleting browser cache on postback programmatically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, caching

Is there anyway to delete my browser cache on post-back programmatically? I am using a jquery function that use ajax on a button click with `cache:true`

```
function CallSyncAjax(url, args, resid, EnableCache, ErrorDivID) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: args,
    cache: EnableCache,
    success: function (data) {
        var StrResponse;
        StrResponse = data.split('@@@');
        if (resid == "1001") {
            LoginByAccountRes(StrResponse[0]);
        }
    }
   })
 }
```

C#:

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    // Set Cacheability...
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(dt);
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(dt.ToFileTime()));

    // Complete OnLoad...
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

the problem is that whenever I refresh the page after one minute and even when I close the browser and reopen it the cache still existed

Comment: why don't try `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);` ?

Comment: try `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`

Comment: because it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these meta tags on your page which says not to cache

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

But programmatically you cannot clear the browser cache due to browser's security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear a browser's history via code because of browsers security reasons, you can only set HTTP header to tell the browser not to chache your pages, using this :

Cache-Control: no-cache

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is only allowed to do certain things on the browser and accessing the browser's cache is not one of them.

However you can control the caching of your webpages using `meta` tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```